# Get Most Occurring Value in a Grouped Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF like this:
`Date   DIS_NR  NUM_EMPLOYEES`
`8/16/2018  868 200`
`8/17/2018  868 150`
`8/18/2018  868 200`
`8/16/2018  776 150`
`8/17/2018  776 250`
`8/18/2018  776 150`

Now, for each DIS_NR, the NUM_EMPLOYEES value with the most occurrences must be used as the benchmark, and any of the other  days that do not have the same value must be flagged.

Final Data should look like this:

`Date   DIS_NR  NUM_EMPLOYEES FLAG`
`8/16/2018  868 200            0`
`8/17/2018  868 150            1`
`8/18/2018  868 200            0`
`8/16/2018  776 150            0`
`8/17/2018  776 250            1`
`8/18/2018  776 150            0`

I grouped by Date and DIS_NR using
     `df1 = DF.groupby(["DIS_NR", "Date"])`
I tried looping over each one and finding the mode but it won't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need flag all dates with maximum sum ? Or need something else?

Comment: Flag all days with less than most frequent value for each district

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it seems like you are agnostic to the `Date` column in the grouping:

```
>>> func = lambda s: s.ne(s.value_counts().idxmax()).astype(int)
>>> df['FLAG'] = df.groupby('DIS_NR')['NUM_EMPLOYEES'].apply(func)

>>> df
        Date  DIS_NR  NUM_EMPLOYEES  FLAG
0 2018-08-16     868            200     0
1 2018-08-17     868            150     1
2 2018-08-18     868            200     0
3 2018-08-16     776            150     0
4 2018-08-17     776            250     1
5 2018-08-18     776            150     0
```

`groupby().transform()` is generally not always the fastest route, but in this case it should be able to use some Cython routines because the methods that are used within `func` are vectorized.  (Rather than needing to be carried out in Python.)

When you pass a function to `.transform()`, it gets applies to each subsetted-Series, which you can view with `.get_groups()`:

```
>>>  df.groupby('DIS_NR')['NUM_EMPLOYEES'].get_group(868)
0    200
1    150
2    200
Name: NUM_EMPLOYEES, dtype: int64

>>>  df.groupby('DIS_NR')['NUM_EMPLOYEES'].get_group(776)
3    150
4    250
5    150
Name: NUM_EMPLOYEES, dtype: int64

>>> func(df.groupby('DIS_NR')['NUM_EMPLOYEES'].get_group(868))
0    0
1    1
2    0
Name: NUM_EMPLOYEES, dtype: int64
```

---

Update:

> For example, If DIS_NR 825 has values (125,243,221) then all of them should be flagged.

```
>>> df
        Date  DIS_NR  NUM_EMPLOYEES
0 2018-08-16     868            200
1 2018-08-17     868            150
2 2018-08-18     868            200
3 2018-08-16     776            150
4 2018-08-17     776            250
5 2018-08-18     776            150
6 2018-08-16     825            100
7 2018-08-17     825            100
8 2018-08-18     825            100
```

In this case, you can throw in a second condition testing for the number of unique values.  Notice also that you're using `.transform()` rather than `.apply()`:

```
func = lambda s: np.where(
    s.nunique() == 1, 1,
    s.ne(s.value_counts().idxmax()).astype(int)
)

>>> df.groupby('DIS_NR')['NUM_EMPLOYEES'].transform(func)
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    0
6    1
7    1
8    1
Name: NUM_EMPLOYEES, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, this need OP.

Comment: Hi Brad, that works except when all values in a District are different. For example, If DIS_NR 825 has values (125,243,221) then all of them should be flagged.

Answer (score 0):

```
DF[‘counts’]=1
df1 = DF.groupby(["DIS_NR", "Date"]).sum()
df1[df1[‘counts’]>1]=0
df1=df1.reset_index() 
DF=pd.merge(DF,df1,on=[“DIS_NR”, “Date”])
```

These are the key steps, after merging, you should see the counts column as the additional column you want.

I am typing this on a phone, there maybe syntax errors above.